# Color a row in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I need to color a row in QTableView. Not Item, I need row! I'm using QSqlQueryModel.As I understood it is doing by QItemDelegate. Help me
Sorry for my English, but I need it!

Comment: Please provide the code in text form not image.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For writing a delegate have a look at this sample: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html, you can set a delegate for a whole row at once with setItemDelegateForRow. However you could also consider writing a descendant of QSqlQueryModel and override the [data](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) method and handle request for the Qt::BackgroundRole

Comment: It doesn't help me (

Comment: `It doesn't help me` what aspect of it doesn't help? What have you tried and why didn't it work out? Please specific with these.

Comment: TrebuchetMS, I can't understood how to use it correctly, so I need detail answer. I need an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.
I wrote this code right here, so idk does it work or not.

```
ItemDelegatePaint::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    if(index.row() == 1) /*check for your row*/ {
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, Qt::red);
        painter->setPen(QColor(Qt::white));
        painter->drawText(option.rect, Qt::AlignCenter, index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
    } else {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

Comment: @sardorkun I update my comment. But please, try to understand how it works, and make it with your own.